# VB.NET Populate textbox with Datagrid first column when datagrid checkbox is selected

Tags: vb.net

I'm a newbie in vb.net. My issues could be simple, but I'm struggling to find a solution.
I have a datagrid (called `DatagridView1`) with first column called `Select_Column` as a check box column and next column is `LossTypes`.

When the user selects the checkbox, I want to display the `LossTypes` in a textbox. It should also work for multi-selection as my datagrid is multiselect

Thanks
Satish

Answer (score 1):

Something like (easier to understand):

```
Dim result as String = ""
For x As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
  If DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("Select_Column").Value Then
     result &= DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("LossTypes").Value & ","
  End If
Next
if result.length > 0 then 
   Textbox1.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(result, result.length-1)
else
   Textbox1.Text = ""
end
```

or using Linq

```
Textbox1.Text = Join((From C DataGridView1.Rows Where C.Cells("Select_Column").Value Select C.Cells("LossTypes").Value).ToArray, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Dim listSelected As New List(String)

Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged()  'DataGridView Cell Value Changed Event
    IF (CBool(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("CheckBoxColumnNamne").Value) Then
        IF NOT listSelected.Contains(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("LossTypes").Value.ToString()) Then
            listSelected.Add(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("LossTypes").Value.ToString())
        End IF
    Else
        IF listSelected.Contains(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("LossTypes").Value.ToString()) Then
            listSelected.Remove(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("LossTypes").Value.ToString())
        End IF
    End If
    textBox1.Text = String.Join(",", listSelected.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Comment: It will not work in ELSE clause. It will try to remove an element that doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response. Solution matched exactly my requirement.

Comment: but, @Satish you should add another condition here to check that the modified value column is `CheckBoxColumn` otherwise application will perform this operation on each cell value change.

Comment: @Shell .. I think I'm applying the condition in a incorrect manner for the Checkbox column. Could you please tell me what exactly you meant or the code for it